# Youtube's API age restriction is empty but the embed player is reporting that "This video is age-restricted"

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I'm getting the response from Youtube's API for some videos, the `contentRating` is empty:

```
   "contentDetails":{
      "duration":"PT1H24M43S",
      "dimension":"2d",
      "definition":"sd",
      "caption":"true",
      "licensedContent":true,
      "regionRestriction":{
         "allowed":[
            "US"
         ]
      },
      "contentRating":{         
      },
      "projection":"rectangular"
   },
```

...but the embed player says that "This video is age-restricted and only available on YouTube" and as a result my app is embedding videos that are unplayable for some users.

In `contentRating`, I was expecting to find `"ytRating": "ytAgeRestricted"` but unfortunately this isn't true in some cases!

Is another (bulletproof) way to find out if the video is age restricted?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not. But you may well file a bug report directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: I did it and I hope for a fix... meanwhile "Invidious" API is a life saver ;)